# Grails: Constraints: Database to allow nulls, but forms may not be blank

Tags: validation, grails, grails-orm, nullable

I have a domain object called OurCompany and I'd like to be able to deliberately insert a row mostly full of nulls. When a user fills in a form though, I'd like to validate it and not allow blanks.

```
class OurCompany {

    static constraints = {        
        enterpriseName blank:false, nullable:true
    }

    String enterpriseName

    static belongsTo = [measurement:Measurement]

}
```

When I create the empty row in the database, I turn off validation and it works fine.

```
ourCompany = new OurCompany();
measurement.addToOurCompany(ourCompany).save(validate:false);
```

Later, when I update the row, the validation is ignored and the record saves even though there is a null / blank value.

```
def ourCompany = loadOrCreateOurCompany();
def industrySectors = loadIndustrySectors();

bindData (ourCompany, params)

ourCompany.validate()
if (ourCompany.hasErrors()) {
    ourCompany.errors.allErrors.each {
        println(it)
    }
} else {            
    ourCompany.save();
}
```

How do I tell grails that I'd like the DATABASE to accept nulls, but when validating, not allow nulls or blanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/single.html#commandObjects) are for

Comment: Thanks Greg. I eventually implemented this, but I wish there was a nicer way. Found it a real time waster.

Comment: I disagree that this solution is ugly and a time waster.  I'm not sure how it could be any better aside from allowing some sort of conditional constraints at the Domain level.  It could be that you've used the Command Object incorrectly so it feels painful.

Comment: Perhaps. When I'm finished my implementation, I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (so far) REALLY ugly. It seems that there is no way to make a grails domain property BOTH nullable and have a CONSTRAINT. The only way to do it is to use a Command Object to do the validation against. In my opinion, it's really quite a painful solution and a rather inelegant, poorly documented methodology. This has been my most unpleasant grails experience.